# Putting Google Map in SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, google-maps, simplemodal

HI.

I am using AJAX so load a page in SimpleModal. On this page I have the Google code to display a Google map. The problem is when I load this page, the page blows up, meaning, the page goes blank, no Firebug errors, not source html, nothing. URL still says it is the correct page, but blank. It has not reloaded, but gone blank.

If I remove the script call to the google maps API, page load fine, but without the map obviously.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Thom

Answer (score 1):

The script call probably has some error either in either it or perhaps in its placement.

You'll need to post some sample code.